# Unable to read the line in file after edit the string inside the textfile

Tags: c#

Suppose that the EditUser method is edit the string in the text file. The problem is that after edit the string in the text file, the ReadUser method wont be able to read the text file anymore. How to solve this issue??

Example string in text file:
123
123
444
444

After edit string in text file:
222
222
333
333

The code is shown below:

```
public void ReadUser()
        {
            int i = 0;
            user = UserID;
            password = Password;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Projects\\AdministratorModule//userTextFile.txt", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                string line;
                bool match = false;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        user1 = line;
                    }
                    else if (i % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        password1 = line;
                    }
                    if (user == user1 && password == password1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Login Successful");
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (match == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Login Failed");
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }

public void EditUser(string currentUserID, string newCurrentUserID, string currentPassword, string newCurrentPassword)
        {

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Projects\\AdministratorModule//userTextFile.txt");
            string[] rows = Regex.Split(sr.ReadToEnd(), "\n");
            sr.Close();

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Projects\\AdministratorModule//userTextFile.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rows[i].Contains(currentUserID))
                {
                    rows[i] = rows[i].Replace(currentUserID, newCurrentUserID);
                }
                if (rows[i].Contains(currentPassword))
                {
                    rows[i] = rows[i].Replace(currentPassword, newCurrentPassword);
                }
                sw.WriteLine(rows[i]);
            }


            sw.Close();

        }
```

Comment: are you getting any error or exceptions?

Comment: @sujithkarivelil No error. It is able to replace the string in the textfile, just that it doesnt read after calling ReadUser() after replacing

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't read? Is that returns empty string or what? You can always use breakpoint to see what exactly happening.

Comment: I'm hoping you answer @jammie 's question, but on  a side note I have to mention this is a very flawed way to manage passwords. If someone has the same password, or a portion of it, of someone else you are going to overwrite everyone's. Same with the user id. And Contains/Replace in general is unreliable because you could match things you don't intend.